# Getting error to post to facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, post, sdk, share

I've already searched google and stackoverflow but I can't find a solution.
I'm trying to integrate facebook into my App so users can suggest new Beer Brands directly to my facebook fanpage thorugh my app. Because right now I'm getting like 3 e-mails a day where users suggest  new beer brands.

What I did:
- Created a facebook developer account, enabled Native Android app and inserted the Key-Hash etc.
- downloaded and integrated the facebook sdk.
- addet internet permission
- integrated the following facebook helper class:

```
package com.celticwolf.nsod; //changed
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class ShareOnFacebook extends Activity{ 
    private static final String APP_ID = "35253892647899";  // changed
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream"};
private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
        private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
        private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";

    private Facebook facebook;
    private String messageToPost;

    public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
            return editor.commit();
        }

        public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
            facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
            return facebook.isSessionValid();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        restoreCredentials(facebook);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.facebook_dialog);

        String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
        if (facebookMessage == null){
            facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
        }
        messageToPost = facebookMessage;
    }

    public void doNotShare(View button){
        finish();
    }
    public void share(View button){
        if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            loginAndPostToWall();
        }
        else {
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
    }

    public void loginAndPostToWall(){
         facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
    }

    public void postToWall(String message){
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", message);
                parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
                try {
                    facebook.request("me");  // <------  here it fails
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                    response.equals("false")) {
                showToast("Blank response.");
            }
            else {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
            }
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    } 

    class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            saveCredentials(facebook);
            if (messageToPost != null){
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
        }
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onCancel() {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and I've addet the following Code to access the helper class:

```
private void shareonfb(){
        Intent postOnFacebookWallIntent = new Intent(this, ShareOnFacebook.class);
        postOnFacebookWallIntent.putExtra("facebookMessage", "Teeeeeeeeeeeest");
        startActivity(postOnFacebookWallIntent);
    }
```

Where it fails:
- I'm able to log into facebook but when it asks if I want to share it fails at the following codeblock:

```
public void postToWall(String message){
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", message);
            parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
            try {
                facebook.request("me");   // <-------------  here it fails and jups to catch
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                response.equals("false")) {
            showToast("Blank response.");
        }
        else {
            showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
        }
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
```

here is the log:  (i've marked the part where it fails)

```
01-06 13:19:53.795: W/ActivityThread(1220): Application com.celticwolf.alex is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-06 13:19:53.805: I/System.out(1220): Sending WAIT chunk
01-06 13:19:54.205: I/System.out(1220): Debugger has connected
01-06 13:19:54.205: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:54.405: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:54.615: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:54.820: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:55.250: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:55.450: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:55.650: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:55.850: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:56.050: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:56.250: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:56.450: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:56.650: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:56.850: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:57.050: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:57.255: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:57.455: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:57.655: I/System.out(1220): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 13:19:57.855: I/System.out(1220): debugger has settled (1373)
01-06 13:19:58.285: I/dalvikvm-heap(1220): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.205MB for 3502096-byte allocation
01-06 13:19:58.400: I/dalvikvm-heap(1220): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.139MB for 6224656-byte allocation
01-06 13:19:58.575: I/MediaPlayer(1220): setLPAflag() in
01-06 13:19:58.575: I/MediaPlayer(1220): mContext is null, can't getMirrorDisplayStatus!!!
01-06 13:19:58.575: I/MediaPlayer(1220): setLPAflag() out
01-06 13:19:58.585: W/MediaPlayer(1220): info/warning (1, 902)
01-06 13:19:58.585: D/MediaPlayer(1220): [DLNA]contentType = 902
01-06 13:19:58.585: D/MediaPlayer(1220): doStart() in
01-06 13:19:58.590: D/MediaPlayer(1220): getIntParameter = 902
01-06 13:19:58.665: D/MediaPlayer(1220): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
01-06 13:19:58.665: I/MediaPlayer(1220): Info (1,902)
01-06 13:19:58.665: D/MediaPlayer(1220): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 5
01-06 13:19:58.665: D/MediaPlayer(1220): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 1
01-06 13:19:58.745: E/(1220): file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!
01-06 13:19:58.745: I/(1220): Attempting to load EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
01-06 13:19:58.805: I/(1220): Loaded EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
01-06 13:19:58.905: I/(1220): Loading GLESv2 implementation /system/lib//egl/libGLESv2_tegra_impl
01-06 13:19:59.350: D/MediaPlayer(1220): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 2
01-06 13:20:00.200: D/MediaPlayer(1220): release() in
01-06 13:20:00.210: D/MediaPlayer(1220): release() out
01-06 13:20:00.745: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(1220): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
01-06 13:20:00.745: I/dalvikvm-heap(1220): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.433MB for 3317776-byte allocation
01-06 13:20:40.855: D/View(1220): ACTION_DOWN before UnsetPressedState. invoking mUnsetPressedState.run()
01-06 13:20:40.870: I/Choreographer(1220): Skipped 1158 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-06 13:20:43.810: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1220): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
01-06 13:20:43.810: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1220): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
01-06 13:20:43.975: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1220): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
01-06 13:20:43.975: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1220): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
01-06 13:20:45.150: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1220): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
01-06 13:20:45.150: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1220): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
01-06 13:21:40.920: D/Facebook-Util(1220): GET URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=AAAFAqIQXNsUBAE18DxmYZCvB9uLEFUSeQEMp3hZASDnjOMllu1Q0BqSTYEoGVEvjZAp8l18eZCt8ZArlPwQ5A08SijSFF00imS2JDO0A9MAZDZD&format=json
01-06 13:21:51.180: W/System.err(1220): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException                                                        <--- at this point it fails
01-06 13:21:51.215: W/System.err(1220):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1208)
01-06 13:21:51.215: W/System.err(1220):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:388)
01-06 13:21:51.220: W/System.err(1220):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:239)
01-06 13:21:51.220: W/System.err(1220):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-06 13:21:51.225: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
01-06 13:21:51.225: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
01-06 13:21:51.230: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
01-06 13:21:51.230: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
01-06 13:21:51.235: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
01-06 13:21:51.235: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
01-06 13:21:51.240: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
01-06 13:21:51.240: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
01-06 13:21:51.245: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
01-06 13:21:51.245: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
01-06 13:21:51.250: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
01-06 13:21:51.255: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
01-06 13:21:51.255: W/System.err(1220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
01-06 13:21:51.255: W/System.err(1220):     at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:219)
01-06 13:21:51.260: W/System.err(1220):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestImpl(Facebook.java:806)
01-06 13:21:51.260: W/System.err(1220):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:732)
01-06 13:21:51.265: W/System.err(1220):     at com.celticwolf.alex.ShareOnFacebook.postToWall(ShareOnFacebook.java:81)
01-06 13:21:51.265: W/System.err(1220):     at com.celticwolf.alex.ShareOnFacebook.share(ShareOnFacebook.java:68)
01-06 13:21:51.265: W/System.err(1220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 13:21:51.265: W/System.err(1220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 13:21:51.270: W/System.err(1220):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3603)
01-06 13:21:51.270: W/System.err(1220):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101)
01-06 13:21:51.270: W/System.err(1220):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17078)
01-06 13:21:51.275: W/System.err(1220):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-06 13:21:51.275: W/System.err(1220):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-06 13:21:51.275: W/System.err(1220):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
01-06 13:21:51.280: W/System.err(1220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
01-06 13:21:51.280: W/System.err(1220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 13:21:51.280: W/System.err(1220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 13:21:51.285: W/System.err(1220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
01-06 13:21:51.285: W/System.err(1220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-06 13:21:51.285: W/System.err(1220):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant make a Network Operation in the main Thread since android 3.0 AFAIK . 
place your call in a sperate thread and if you need to update `UI` use either `handlers` or `AsyncTask`

example :

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
{
public Boolean doInBackground(String ...message){

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", message[0]);
            parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
            try {
                facebook.request("me");   // <-------------  here it fails and jups to catch
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                response.equals("false")) {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
        else {
             return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
} 

public void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
        if(result == Boolean.TRUE){
 showToast("posted successfully");
}else{
 showToast("couldn't post to FB.");
}
        finish();
}
}
```

see this [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: Thank You !!! It worked !! In case anyone is wondering. I replaced the failing codeblock with Nammaris solution and called it via: new MyAsyncTask().execute(message);  One more question.  Do you know how to post on a facebook Fanpage instead?